# Swift believes non-nil value is actually nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have two text boxes, `passwordTextField` and `emailTextField`. Values are entered into each. When I hit print, the values print in the console.
However, I am receiving the following error when using the next function to populate a text box on the next view controller.

**Note**
This was working not a few hours ago and I have changed nothing, so I am unsure how or why this now does not work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var registerButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ABC") as! ABCViewController
    self.present(next, animated: true,completion: nil)

    let nameText = self.emailTextField.text!
    let passwordText = self.passwordTextField.text!
    print(nameText) // prints email
    print(passwordText) // prints password

    next.username.text = nameText // prints error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    next.password.text = passwordText
}
```

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

But non-nil values are displaying when printing out.

Comment: The thing you are printing is not what is nil. The thing that is nil is `next.username` not `nameText`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is unreliable because it's not guaranteed that the view in the second controller is loaded right after the `present` line.
All outlets are `nil` until the view is available.

Declare temporary properties in `ABCViewController` and populate the text fields in viewDidLoad

```
class ABCViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    var tempName = ""
    var tempPassword = "" 

    // .....

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        username.text = self.tempName 
        password.text = self.tempPassword
    }
}
```

In `registerButtonPressed` assign the values to the temporary properties and present the controller, nothing else.

```
@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ABC") as! ABCViewController
    next.tempName = self.emailTextField.text!
    next.tempPassword = self.passwordTextField.text!
    self.present(next, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I agree with this also

Comment: i cannot add the username.text = self.name properties to the viewDidLoad of the next view controller.  It does not recognize the variable "username" as that is not declared in the current view controller.  I've done everything else you suggested with the same result.

Comment: The line `next.username.text` in your code implies that there is an `@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!` (or `UILabel`) in `ABCViewController`

Comment: I've added these variables and still get the same result.

Comment: I updated the answer by adding the outlets and changing a few variable names to avoid confusion. The outlets must be connected in Interface Builder though.

Comment: yes unfortunately this is how I have it setup and still receive this error.  as i stated it was working a short time ago and now is not with no changes.   thanks for your help...

Comment: Try to disconnect and reconnect the outlets. By the way regarding the topic of your question: Swift doesn't *believe*, the compiler **knows** 

Comment: Issue is rampant across my app now.  I have 10 different VCs where this is now occurring and this code previously worked.  Arrrghhhhhh!!!